# How can I add a YouTube video to the Watch History with the YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm making a site with the YouTube Data API 3.0 where users can watch YouTube videos. I need these videos to go to the Watch History so I can know that they've been watched, but playing videos with the YouTube Player API doesn't add them. I've added the video ID to the user's watch history playlist id with playlistItems.insert and the video shows up on the Watch History playlist if I go to youtube.com. However, it isn't returned in the list when I request the playlist items with the Data API.

Does anyone know how to add videos to the watch history so that they're returned in API calls? Alternatively, is there a way to use the Player API so that the authenticated user get the video on their watch history?

Here is the code to add a video to the user's watch history:

```
gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
  'part': 'snippet',
  'resource': {
    'snippet': {
      'playlistId': Cache.fetch('my_channel').relatedPlaylists.watchHistory,
      'position': 0,
      'resourceId': {
        'kind': 'youtube#video',
        'videoId': video_id,
      }
    }
  }
}).execute(callback);
```

Comment: Could you please share the your code of the working playlistItems.insert call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for connect and request using http and json

```
try {

        URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet"
                + "&key=AIzaSyAhONZJpMCBqCfQjFUj21cR2klf6JWbVSo"
                + "&access_token=" + access_token);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String input = "{ \"snippet\": {\"playlistId\": \"WL\",\"resourceId\": {\"videoId\": \""+videoId+"\",\"kind\": \"youtube#video\"},\"position\": 0}}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }
```

if you see an error add this but this is not a good job.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Inserting operation is forbidden in watch history.