# YouTube APi V3 PlaylistItem.insert - forbidden/playlistItemsNotAccessible error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to insert into the Watch History playlist using YouTube API v3. I've used the API explorer and authenticated my session.

I enter in the details required and give it my body:

```
    {
      "snippet": 
      {
        "playlistId": "HLbUVKMjpXy9V9C1R1vpV_8g",
        "resourceId": 
        {
          "videoId": "RgKAFK5djSk",
          "kind": "youtube#video"
        }
      }
    }
```

But then the API Explorer says: You do not have permission to execute this method.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: which scope did you use to authenticate ?

Comment: Youtubepartner, YoutubeForceSsl and Youtube - are you able to execute the method in the API explorer or is it just me?

Comment: I've tried it in the API explorer and I get the same error. Are you sure the playlist actually exists? Based off the IDs you've given, you should see the playlist with the url [`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgKAFK5djSk&list=HLbUVKMjpXy9V9C1R1vpV_8g`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgKAFK5djSk&list=HLbUVKMjpXy9V9C1R1vpV_8g), however I don't see a playlist for it.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I'm trying to insert a video into a users Watch History (which is a playlist in any case). the playlistId above is my Watch History playlistId. I need to send the playlistId along with the videoId and type of resource that I want to insert into the Watch History playlist

Comment: There are similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405960/adding-video-to-youtube-watch-history) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549572/how-can-i-add-a-youtube-video-to-the-watch-history-with-the-youtube-data-api) which report similar things. It might just not be possible to insert into Watch History. This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642) may be related.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. At the moment I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing the code to automate the "batch insert" process, then you should wait for a few seconds between each insertion. It looks like the API endpoint does not support multiple insertions to the same playlist within the same second, and that's why it always return a 500 error.